# HTTP Status 500 - Could not get next sequenced ID for sequence name: Visitor

Tags: java, apache, ant, ofbiz

I am trying to run ofbiz on by local machine(localhost) and my operating system is ubuntu 14.04. Till now I have installed JRE, JDK and apache ant and my system also contains apache server and running.
Then went to directory contains build.xml and run following command

> sudo ant run-install

Then replace new build.xml file and run following command

> ant load-demo
> ant start

Then server will starts and code is accessible with url https://localhost:8443/ecommerce/control/checkLogin and everything is working fine.
Now issue is on next day when i start server with same ant start command server starts fine but on accessing it starts giving me error like
**HTTP Status 500 - Could not get next sequenced ID for sequence name: Visitor**. Screen shot of error is added below:
[image]

I am new to ofbiz please help me find:

> 1.Why this is error coming on previously worked code?
>   2.How to solve this issue?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got same issue when i tried to run ofbiz with ant on ubuntu.
Ofbiz uses derby as database by default and connection files are available in your project directory. This issue comes when code not able to connect with database because inaccessibility of connection file.
In my case, It is due to file permission. Check if you have file permission to all your files as it solves mine.

> cd *path/to/your/ofbiz/folder*
> sudo chmod 777 -R your project name

You can change permissions from above according to your need and security.

Comment: Thanks buddy, I have wasted my whole day to find solution and not this one. And this one finally work for me! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe late to the game, but for a better experience ask such questions in the user ml of the Apache OFBiz project, see here how to connect to more OFBiz experts: https://ofbiz.apache.org/mailing-lists.html